# Vimeo embed still play on background after ActionbarActivity intent is paused/finished

Tags: android, android-intent, video, vimeo, vimeo-player

I've implement a WebView to load a Vimeo video using iframe but when I play the video and pressed the back button which will get me back to the previous intent, the Vimeo video is still playing on the background. This also happens when I pressed the home button and I don't know what to do anymore since these workarounds doesn't work on my end:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    webView.onPause();
    webView.stopLoading();
    if (webView != null){
        webView.stopLoading();
        webView.loadUrl("");
        webView.reload();
        webView = null;
    }

    finish();
}
```

Note: the video stops when I scroll on the listview from the first activity where the list of this embeded videos is displayed as thumbnails but doesn't stop when pressed the home button while the activity is paused on background.

Comment: hey were you able to resolve this

Comment: actually i am not able to stop video during scroll how did you do that

Comment: did it work? I have same problem here ?